# Python object names and the interactive interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter, interactive

When I define a class and create an instance of it, entering the instance name into the shell returns a memory location. No surprise there, but does anybody know how to define a class in such a way that entering its name into a shell will actually return something other than a memory location?

Example:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> foo = np.array([1,2,3])
>> foo
>> array([1, 2, 3])
```

It would be nice if I could get something like this going.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method is for:

```
>>> class point(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "point(%d, %d)" % (self.x, self.y)
>>> x = point(3, 4)
>>> x
point(3, 4)
```

In the absence of a custom `__repr__` implementation, you'll see exactly what you're describing in the question:

```
>>> class defaultPoint(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y  
... 
>>> p = defaultPoint(0, 3)
>>> p
<__main__.defaultPoint object at 0x16767b0>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `__str__` method do the same too? I'm learning Python, so I'm not sure if one could do this for an external module like numpy.

Comment: See the link in the answer pointing to the documentation for the Python data model to understand the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`.

Comment: Got it, former is for formal string representation, while the latter is for informal user-consumed output. Also `__str__` only works when `print` function is called on the object.

Comment: `_-str__`also gets called whenever an object gets converted to string (e.g., `str(myObject)`) or is formatted as a string.

Comment: Thanks! I spend all last night digging through special methods, but somehow missed __repr__ and __str__.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `__repr__` method on the class.

Answer (score 1):

By default we have the magic methods for the python classes , two of those magic methods will help us to do this thing, those are

```
__str__
__repr__
```

I you use **repr** you can  achieve what you desire .
and if you use **str** it will return what you are returning in that method while using print statement

Note that you should return what you want to display from those methods